# SQL for checking a set of values in 20 columns

Tags: sql, db2

I have to check for a set of values in around 20 columns,

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE
         COL1 IN ('01','02'..'10')
      OR COL2 IN ('01','02'..'10')  
      OR COL3 IN ('01','02'..'10')
      OR COL4 IN ('01','02'..'10')
      .
      .
      .
      .
      OR COL20 IN ('01','02'..'10')
```

Is there any alternate way which will be more effective?

Comment: If you put the set of values into a table adn used a join you'd still have a big OR clause, but you wouldn't have repeating set data.

Comment: Sure sounds like you should normalize your data structure to simplify your queries.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

**edit:** oh I didn't see the db2 tag... This would work in T-SQL.  I'm not sure about DB2 though.

```
CREATE TABLE #values ([myVal] VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO #values([myVal])
VALUES ('01'),('02'),...,('10');

SELECT
    *
FROM MY_TABLE A
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM #values
    WHERE [myVal] IN (A.[Col1],A.[Col2],...)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`select *  from MYTABLE where ( select  name from sysibm.syscolumns where tbname = 'MYTABLE' and tbcreator='MYID' and name like ('COL_')) IN ('01',..,'10');`

Even if you select column names from **sysibm.syscolumns**, it is assumed to be a string variable not a column name. It seems not possible with pure SQL statement.

You can try Stored Procedure.